# What is the output of this Python higher order function?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a question I generated myself after looking at code from my homework.

```
def compose(f,g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

def thrice(f):
    return compose(compose(f,f),f)

def add1(x):
    return x+1
```

It seems that when I tried `compose(thrice,add1)(x)` where x is some random integer I decided to use, it returns a different memory location each time. From my own knowledge of lambda calculus, the above code will reduce to `thrice(integer)`, but I'm not very clear why the memory location of some function will be invoked, even if so why is it always changing and not the same one?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not do lambda calculus. Lambda calculus doesn't deal with the concept of "memory location". You're mixing theory and practice :)

Calling compose will always create a new lambda, because that's what `lambda ...: ...` expression does. Even if you call it on the same, constant arguments, you'll get a different object:

```
In [2]: id(lambda: 1)
Out[2]: 4380732272

In [3]: id(lambda: 1)
Out[3]: 4380642296
```

Also, even if you get to the number itself, two equal values will only share the memory location in cPython if they're <= 256. Values above that get allocated when needed.

```
In [14]: id(256)
Out[14]: 4497541712
In [15]: id(256)
Out[15]: 4497541712

In [16]: id(257)
Out[16]: 4528835408
In [17]: id(257)
Out[17]: 4528833008
```